# Problem with multiple input file in *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, input, ngfor

I'm having trouble targeting the correct input when it's in a *ngFor loop. When I add an image with the first input (Certificat dimmatriculation), I show a placeholder image and a delete button to reset the input (which works) but it shows under both div.

I want to target only the input where I added the actual image. I do have a ViewChild but I can't seem to make it work.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0B44.jpg)

and here's the code:

```
<div class="files">
     <div class="single-file" *ngFor="let file of files">
          <h5>{{file.title}}</h5>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="{{file.slug}}" class="inputfile" #fileInput (change)="addFile(fileInput.files[0])" />
          <label for="{{file.slug}}" *ngIf="!hasFile || isDeleted">
          <img class="d-none d-xl-inline-block" src="assets/images/addImg.png" alt="">
          Ajouter votre photo
          <img class="d-block d-xl-none" src="assets/images/addImg_big.png" alt="">
     </label>
     <div class="placeholder" *ngIf="hasFile && !isDeleted">
          <img [src]="imageUrl" />
      </div>
      <div class="deleteImg" *ngIf="hasFile && !isDeleted" (click)="deleteFile()">
          <div class="btn btn-outline"><img src="assets/images/delete-x-icon.png" alt="Supprimer">Supprimer</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and in the .ts:

I declare all my variables

```
file: File;
imageUrl: string | ArrayBuffer = '../app/assets/images/imgAdded.png';
hasFile = false;
isDeleted = false;

@ViewChild('fileInput', { static: false }) myFileInput: ElementRef;

files: any = [{
    'title': 'Certificat dimmatriculation',
    'slug': 'immatriculation',
    'input': '#fileInput1'
}, {
    'title': 'Preuve dassurance',
    'slug': 'insurance',
    'input': '#fileInput2'
}];

addFile(file: File) {
    if (file) {
        this.hasFile = !this.hasFile;
        // this.fileName = file.name;
        this.file = file;

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        reader.onload = event => {
            this.imageUrl = this.imageUrl;
            // this.imageUrl = reader.result;
        };
    }
}

deleteFile() {
    this.isDeleted = !this.isDeleted;
    this.myFileInput.nativeElement.value = '';
}
```

Comment: I can't quite see what you're trying to achieve here. How is `files` populated? You've not included `files` in your component code.

Comment: Yes - where is `files`?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I had it in my .ts and will add it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem at the moment is that you are trying to manage individual `file` properties by using component-level properties. I would recommend using file properties to store uploaded image data. All actions are then scoped to the `file` instances.

I have simplified your code examples for the purposes of the demo, and to help you see what approach I've taken.

I am using a property on the individual files called `imageUrl` to store the uploaded image data url. The presence of a value in this property means that an image has been uploaded. The property is cleared when the image is deleted.

**component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let file of files">
  <h5>{{file.title}}</h5>    
  <label *ngIf="!file.imageUrl">
    <input type="file" (change)="addFile(file, $event)" />
    Ajouter votre photo
  </label>  
  <ng-container *ngIf="file.imageUrl">
    <img [src]="file.imageUrl" />
    <button (click)="deleteFile(file)">Supprimer</button>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

All actions are now performed on the individual `file` objects, and need to be passed in to the event handlers. You could alternatively use an array index instead of the object reference.

There is also potentially some confusion between the `file` instances and the file uploaded from the input. I would recommend renaming your `files` and `file` variables to something else if possible, and reserving `file` for when you are dealing with the file input.

**component.ts**

```js
addFile(file, event) {
  const uploaded = event.target.files[0];
  if (!uploaded) {
    return;
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    file.imageUrl = reader.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(uploaded);
}

deleteFile(file) {
  file.imageUrl = '';
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcgwrq